# Call to undefined function curl_init()?

Tags: php, curl

When i am going to implement Authorize.net payment gateway. However, I got this error:

> Call to undefined function curl_init()

Please let me know what is wrong in it.

Comment: You don't have curl support in your PHP. This question has been [asked many times here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=call+to+undefined+function+curl_init)

Comment: for PHP7 ... I added php dir path in system enviroment varible, deleted libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from apache/bin, keep these dll in php directory and its work.

Comment: Had this problem but none of these answers worked.  The one that did turned out to be here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116448/cannot-enable-php-curl-on-ubuntu-18-04-php-7-2

Comment: If all else fails, it maybe an incompatible (older) version of Apache. Upgrading from 2.4.18 to 2.4.46 fixed the problem for me and others.

Answer (score 921, accepted):

If you're on **Windows**:

Go to your php.ini file and remove the `;` mark from the beginning of the following line:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

After you have saved the file you *must* restart your HTTP server software (e.g. Apache) before this can take effect.

---

For **Ubuntu 13.0 and above**, simply use the debundled package. In a terminal type the following to install it and do not forgot to restart server.

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Or if you're using the old PHP5

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
```

Then **restart apache** to activate the package with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Make sure you restart your Apache server after making this change.

Comment: If this doesn't work, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380670/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-error-in-wamp-2-2). It provides a link for downloading a "fixed" `php_curl.dll` for PHP 5.3.13 (or 5.4.3). I had everything configured right but `curl` just wasn't being loaded (not showing up in `phpinfo()`). This fixed my issue.

Comment: if you are using from cmd, there is anoher php.ini file, more info there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line

Comment: on linux, you uncomment or add `extension=php_curl.so` in your php.ini and restart apache

Comment: @AndrewCheong, Weird, why would you have a corrupted `php_curl.dll`? Are you sure you downloaded the official PHP from php.net?

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes, Wouldn't `extension=php_curl.so` work on Linux/Unix/OSX?

Comment: works fine in ubuntu 15.10 and no need to change the php.ini

Comment: Issue with dependencies - the command with dependencies for Ubuntu 14.04 here is : "sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl" source: "http://askubuntu.com/questions/530323/how-to-make-curl-and-php-available-when-installed-from-xampp"

Comment: On Ubuntu Apache, it was not enough to add the extension to php.ini, I also had to add it to /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini,

Comment: So for php 5.6 u need to `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl` ... :I . On my envoirement curl was woriking fine on the nginx server but when i tried to use it in phpunit it gave me an error.  That could be the same for other libs like php-xml ... i needed to  install 5.6 explict!

Comment: ```sudo apt-get install php-curl``` then ```sudo service apache2 reload``` done!

Comment: Didn't work for me in Windows, fixed by copying `libeay32.dll`, `libsasl.dll` and `libssh2.dll` from folder contains `php.exe` to `C:\Windows\System`, `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

Comment: If you are running Linux, as @Simon said, don't forget to restart apache for the change to take effect.

Comment: NginX did not require a restart. "apt-get install php-curl" on Debian 9 worked.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04, sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl

Comment: Thanks, just don't forget to ´sudo service apache2 restart´ (if on LAMP)

Comment: I used php5.6 on ubuntu so `apt-get install php5.6-curl` worked fine also. Apt-get couldn't locate `php5-curl` with an error.

Comment: Apache 2.4.18 won't load Curl (even if it is checked in wamp). You have to update your Apache version to make it work.

Comment: If after making this it still does not works, then read this (on Windows): https://stackoverflow.com/a/49747761/3255692

Comment: for a fresh ubuntu 18 `sudo apt install php-curl` worked for me

Comment: this answer is pure evil :-D

Comment: In ubuntu check php version by `php -v`. my php version was `7.3`. install php curl based on your version `apt-get install php7.3-curl`. restart your apache2 `service apache2 restart`

Comment: note in my case the entry doesn't have the PHP prefix; it's like that: `extension=curl`

Comment: Well... it has always worked for me (on Windows). I didn't change anything to the settings, but today I suddenly got this message. I checked the settings, they're still ok.

Answer (score 18):

The CURL extension `ext/curl` is not installed or enabled in your PHP installation. Check the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php) for information on how to install or enable CURL on your system.

Comment: (Win32) I also had to add `c:\php` to my PATH.  I learned that reading the manual from the link above.  The manual said `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` must both be on the PATH for the module to work.