# WampServer - browscap.ini is not there and curl_init() do not work

Tags: curl, wampserver, php, browscap

I am running `wampserver 2.4` on `windows` machine and when I checked `phpinfo()` the `local value` and `master value` of `browscap` was `no value`. So can anybody tell me how to configure the server for `browscap`. other issue is that `curl_init()` method does not work in it. says`call to undefined function curl_inint()` any help with this to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newer version of wampserver both of these things comes already enabled, and xampp is alot more better than this in every way.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the curl extension in your php.ini file located in your php root. Also see [this (duplicated) issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382539/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init)

Please do a Google / StackOverflow search first next time!