# How can I enable php5_curl.dll if it is not listed in my php.ini

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am getting the error of:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/storium/includes/GCM.php on line 31
```

I have searched on the web and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382539/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init) but the line is not listed in my `php.ini`, also I have tried installing php5-curl but nothing works. Any idea? I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't use dlls... and if the curl extension isn't listed in your .ini file, then perhaps you should list it... of course, on ubuntu, you don't put extensions into the main php.ini, you put them into /etc/php.d

Comment: How can i enable the curl_init() function?

Comment: just install that function, in your answer you have the solution "sudo apt-get install php5-curl"...