# Wordpress php curl support

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have this code `$ch = curl_init();` and I have an error of **Call to undefined function curl_init()**
I know that I need to enable/install the curl that's why my question is can I install the curl support in php.ini in wordpress? Or I still need to install php to install it there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382539/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (if on debian/ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-curl
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Otherwise, read the [install notes](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php) for php curl support.  It states:

"To use PHP's cURL support you must also compile PHP --with-curl[=DIR] where DIR is the location of the directory containing the lib and include directories."

Comment: So with your answer, I still need to install php? @johnjg12