# curl_init() error Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php

why I always get Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init().
I have set extension:php_curl in php.ini and install php-curl too.
but not working. .
everyone help me?

Comment: your php and apache version?

Comment: I think this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382539/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init

Comment: What PHP version and platform are you using? To make sure it is properly installed, use: extension_loaded('curl')

Comment: yes I know but I have followed it. and still keep the error. @Priya

Comment: I use php version 7.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install curl

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

if you are using php 7

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

and restart server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: thank you it work on me.  when I used sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl.