# POST JSON from PHP to API

Tags: php, json, api, e-commerce

I want to send orders from an ecommerce to an API with order details.
Must sent to specified URL + the GUID in header, I use it but got no result.
I can save null in the fields with that value. Please help, I'm new with PHP.
The PHP is:

```php
<?php

$url = 'https://url.ro:447/api/WebShop/SetOrderInvoiceAndPayment';
$data = array(
    "Cif"               => null,
    "Cnp"               => null,
    "Email"             => "catalin.duca@mail.ro",
    "FirstName"         => "Catalin",
    "LastName"          => "Duca",
    "CollectionId"      => "1",
    "DocumentDate"      => "2020-12-22 11:57:43",
    "DocumentDueDate"   => null,
    "OrderDeliveryDate" => null,
    "OrderExplanation"  => "test",
    "OrderNo"           => "11111",
    "PartnerId"         => null,

    "Payments" => array (), 

    "Products" => array (
        "Bbd"           => null,
        "Lot"           => null,
        "ProductId"     => "49102",
        "Qpp"           => null,
        "Quantity"      => "1",
        "RetailPrice"   => "18.69",
        "ServiceName"   => null,
        "SubgestId"     => null
    )
);

$postdata = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Guid: demoguid'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r ($result);
?>
```

Comment: This JSON works if I use it from Postman with POST method to that URL.

Comment: Have you tried copying the `curl` code from Postman?

Comment: Also, in what way does your code fail? What is the `curl_error`?

Comment: @El_Vanja i use the curl from Postman, but didn't work. No error, is loading and no error text.

Comment: error is: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /in/VGjR4:34
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /in/VGjR4 on line 34

Process exited with code 255.

Comment: In that case see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382539/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init).

Comment: I got that error when i use the php from other test website, on mine still no error show.