# Have a good resut on testing json on github

Tags: php, github

I tried to check on github is a json file exists but it return always false. The link is correct

```
var_dump (is_file('https://api.github.com/repos/ClicShopping/ClicShopping_V3/contents/includes/ClicShopping/version.json?ref=master'));
```

If I tried this , not works also :

```
var_dump (json_decode('https://api.github.com/repos/ClicShopping/ClicShopping_V3/contents/includes/ClicShopping/version.json?ref=master'));
```

Do you know a way to test that correctly ?

thank you

Comment: I added the `php` tag for you, good idea to have all the relevant tags. This has not much to do with github, but everything to do with php/http/stuff like that.

Comment: turns out it did have everything to do with github..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fetch the file first with a `GET` request. Otherwise you are just checking if that particular string (the url) is a file (which it is not, it is a string).

In addition, that particular github api **requires** a `User-Agent` header, otherwise the request is rejected. ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#user-agent-required)). They recommend you put your github username in the header so they can contact you.

With that said, this should work (uses curl to fetch from the url):

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "your-github-username");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/repos/ClicShopping/ClicShopping_V3/contents/includes/ClicShopping/version.json?ref=master");
$res = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump(json_decode($res));
curl_close($curl);
```

You might have to do `sudo apt install php-curl` or install it some other way if `curl_init` is undefined (instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382539/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init))

Comment: Thank you but the result is null.

Comment: I have modified my answer, this should work now, please mark the answer as accepted if it works for you