# WAMP directory in different location?

Tags: php, wamp

I'll start by saying I' completely new to WAMP.

The issue I'm having is that I have my WAMP program director installed in C:\Program Files- however, my C:\ drive is filling up fast and the site I work on is extremely large. Is it possible to have WAMP installed on C:\ but direct WAMP to look for the index file in say E:\www\???

Comment: look up DocumentRoot in httpd.conf

Comment: not sure if you've looked at this but I would recommend it if you are trying to get a WAMP server up and running http://www.easyphp.org/ I use it when I need to test anything local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to edit the DocumentRoot location in `httpd.conf`

I believe the default is: `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"`

You should be able to amend this to a new folder: `DocumentRoot "E:/www/"`

You might need to also change the `<Directory "c:/wamp/www">` listing as well.

You can open httpd.conf via the WAMP app. It comes under Apache.

Comment: I've figured it out! Thank all of you so much! Excited!

Answer (score 0):

try go to

```
 C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\httpd.conf
```

change `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/" to DocumentRoot "e:/wamp/www/"` (line 178)

For more :- [Moving WAMP and Wordpress to another drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015476/moving-wamp-and-wordpress-to-another-drive)

Comment: This file appears as a "pink feather" and is labeled an application. When I double-click it, it opens up a DOS window, I quickly read something about a syntax error and it closes on me?

I have 2 Apache folders - Apache 2.2.2 and Apache 2.4.4

Comment: use Apache 2.4.4 and open it with notepad or any editer with open with right click

Comment: see what path is in wamp. and open with notepad or similar app.

Comment: @RakeshSharma if he use apache 2.2.2 in wamp then that will not work. He needs to see which one is used in wamp menu.

Comment: WAMP has 2.4.4 set (chckmarked). I got the editable file open, but the directory settings aren't on the same line as 2.2.2

Comment: it is not important what line is it. just change the path. and also change path to Directory tag to set up access rights.

Comment: your welcome :) then need to upvote and accept helpful answer